# what is ': this.only' in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone explain to me the script's (given below) constructor, what ': this.only' means:

```
class BorderRadius extends BorderRadiusGeometry {


  const BorderRadius.all(Radius radius) : this.only(

    topLeft: radius,

    topRight: radius,

    bottomLeft: radius,

    bottomRight: radius,

  );
```

I am learning Dart and trying to understand the class/widgets of flutter and it's built code.

Thank you.

Comment: 1st ex. BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))   2nd ex. BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10) ),

Comment: @JBJason So are they 2 different constructors, separated by ':', or ':' got any other functionality?

Comment: @JBJason I got it in the accepted answer that it's a redirecting constructor. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a redirecting constructor in the same class.  Look at BorderRadius.only for its definition.

Comment: I was thinking that. Thank you for your answer. But I am not interested in the definition of that contractor, I want to know what ':' is doing. Is it the syntax for named constructors or ':' is doing something else?

Comment: @noname That colon is literally how you make a redirecting constructor. See this: https://dart.dev/language/constructors#redirecting-constructors

Comment: @DhafinRayhan oh okay okay. I missed that part in study. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a redirecting constructor.